I want to recreate this in 3D. How can I model the skin around the sqheres?
Is there a tool to make this possible and what shapes can I do this with?


Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

Please verbally describe what your issue is, be specific and and use relevant keywords. Avoid referencing images or links as alternative to words, try to stay away from vague references like "this happens", "issue with", "like so", which make the post impossible to find for someone using search. Instead describe what "it" is, be descriptive, succinct and detailed. It may not be immediately obvious to users trying to help what you mean. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

What have you tried as far? What are you struggling with? There are many ways to do this: modelling, sculpting, simulation, just drawing... All involve many steps that might require making quite lengthy tutorial which is generally considered to have the potential of being off-topic here on its own, but without narrowing this question down to some more specific approach you are after it's really impossible to answer this with a single answer. You should edit it and narrow it down. You should also do at least some research before asking. Have you thought about how you want to make this?

Maybe the context could narrow it down to more reasonable approaches. What is the context? What do you want to make? Animation, stills? Why? For what purpose?

Have you tried using the sculpting tools?

I finally figured it out how to do the skin part by using a cube with a lot of subdivisions and then shrinkwrap. after applying the effect I smoothed and did other modifications on the object in sculpt mode.
